# How to retrieve elements stored in ArrayList from a method in a different class and display it in the main class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a simple program whereby I've created a Java form that is connected to a database.

For the Java part, I have two classes. One class that contains all the GUI elements and I have created another class called engine to perform processing stuff.

The program is simple, just add a name and age to a database and the other function is just display all elements added so far.

For the engine class, I have a method to get all the elements stored in the database and I have saved it in an ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllRecord() throws SQLException
{
    Statement st = connection().createStatement();
    st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM RECORD");
    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    String age2;
    String name2;

while(rs.next()){
    name2 = rs.getString("NAME");
    dRecList.add(name2);
    double age = rs.getDouble("AGE");
    age2 = String.valueOf(age);
    dRecList.add(age2);
}
   return dRecList;
}
```

For the main class, I created a button that would access the engine class to get all the record and it does provide all the elements.

```
private void showBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    engine en2 = new engine();
 for(int i=1; i < en2.getAllRecord().size(); i++){
            resultTxt.append(en2.getAllRecord().get(i));
        }
}
```

The issue I faced is, How do I display each element in a new line in a textArea?

Comment: So you are getting all results correctly for the ArrayList? Why don´t you just append an other "\n" behind the result from the ArrayList?

Comment: Hi, I created a method that returns the arrayList and in the main class I created an object variable to call that method. Therefore the results are shown.

I think the method is returning all the elements as one result and perhaps its difficult to break each element down and display it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

add a `\n`

```
for(int i=1; i < en2.getAllRecord().size(); i++){
            resultTxt.append(en2.getAllRecord().get(i)+"\n");
        }
```

**EDIT** it would be better to use a for-each loop

```
for(String data: en2.getAllRecord()){
                resultTxt.append(data+"\n");
          }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply however it did not return any result in the textArea.

I'm thinking there's probably a way  to access the arrayList variable dRecList and display the items in it, however I've not been successful though.

Comment: It would be even better to use a `StringBuilder` to create the `String` and then set it at the TextArea's text.

Comment: Hi Guys, I tried the following and got a result but the elements still appear in one line instead of each element being displayed in a new line

    try {
            resultTxt.append(en2.getAllRecord().toString());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: @JasvinderSingh,did you add `\n` ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, not mandatory but best practice is, to create an object representing table model with getter and setter on name and age attributes

when you cycle the resultset you shoud instanciate a new model object (with name and age) and adding it to a list of model object (same list for all object obviously)

with this list then, you can do what you want